# Tomcat AccessLogValve Pattern Reload without Restart

Tags: tomcat, reload, server.xml

Is it somehow possible to reload the changes in the server.xml without restarting Tomcat?

I want to make several changes to my access_log format (in org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve -> pattern='...') on many servers but I don't want to restart my Tomcat for each change in the server.xml. Is it possible to have Tomcat reload the configuration changes in the pattern without restarting?

(Tomcat 7.0.29)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it looks like the answer is 'no'. Per [Defining a context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) in the Tomcat 7 docs:

> **It is NOT recommended to place  elements directly in the
>   server.xml file.** This is because it makes modifying the **Context**
>   configuration more invasive since the main `conf/server.xml` file cannot
>   be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.

There's a lot of bold text there. Surely they must be serious.

Comment: Can you place a Valve anywhere else than server.xml?

Comment: Yep ... it looks like a Valve can be defined in an Engine, Host, or Context. The one sitting in server.xml by default is nested within the Host.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Nested_Components

Answer (score 1):

First, I absolutely agree with Michael Scheper that when tomcat says they don't like elements placed directly in the server.xml, they mean it. Having said that, there could a filthy hack that you could try at your own risk. AccessLogValve class in tomcat seems to have public setter methods for 'directory' and 'format'. Forget I ever said that.